# Canadian Visa for Iraqi Citizens

Tags: visas, canada, iraqi-citizens

I am from Iraq and I want a Canadian visa. I have an Iraqi passport but I currently don't have an embassy where I can apply for a visa for Canada. How do I get one?

Comment: In which country?

Comment: And what kind of visa?

Comment: [Visa Application Centre in Erbil, Iraq](http://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/Iraq/index.html) for visitor visas in Iraq.

Answer (score 8):

Canadian visas for Iraqi citizens are processed through the [visa office in Amman, Jordan](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/missions/amman.asp). You can [begin the process](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp) by [applying online](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/e-services/mycic.asp) (if you have an internationally recognized credit card) or filing a [paper application](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5256ETOC.asp). In either case, you will be able to bring your documents and give your biometrics at a VAC in [Erbil, Iraq](http://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/Iraq/index.html) or [Amman, Jordan](http://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/Jordan/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

See these web sites for information:

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/

http://www.international.gc.ca/cip-pic/mission_info-info_mission.aspx?lang=eng

In case the links do not work, http://www.cic.gc.ca/ is the web site for Citizen and Immigration Canada, which has information on how to get visas to study/work/immigrate to Canada. The link I gave above was to a list of the visa processing offices as of Oct 2015.

http://www.international.gc.ca is the web site for Foreign Affairs, Trade and Development Canada, which is the government department responsible for all of Canada's embassies, high commissions, and consulates. The link I gave above was to the list of these offices outside Canada as of Oct 2015.

Even if the home-page links do not work, you should always be able to find the relevant information by searching for the name of the government department, as given above.

Both web sites are available in English or French through the home page.

Comment: Could you summarise the content of those links? Links have a tendency do become invalid after a while, which would make this answer useless.